# Connecting 2 PCBs which are spaced at 1.4 mm

Tags: connector

The mechanical enclosure that we have chosen for our product has a provision of accommodating 2 PCBs, the distance between them is 1.4 mm. Certain signals (16 signals) are to be taken from one board to another. Please suggest the type of connector that can be used for this purpose. We couldn't find board-board connector and FPC type-B connector that match our requirement.

Comment: If you can't have a custom pin based connector of precise dimensions custom made, they're just signals, have you considered using thin plastic flat ribbon cable? If the 1.4mm between the boards was too tight for the bend you could use the outer sides for a wider radius.

Comment: 1) Even if I use flat cable, I need to have one side of it to go to a connector and another side solderable for development purpose. We are not finding such cables. 2) There is no much space around the boards to bend.

Comment: Have you disassembled a smart phone or laptop?  You can get very small signal cables that can be bent, curved or folded, and they can be attached with wire glue when not solderable type, although the detachable connectors for them are very low profile.

Comment: I am not aware of such cables. Can you please suggest me the part number of such cables so that I can check the feasibility.

Comment: It's called flat flexible cable(FFC).  You'll have to sort through all the options on digikey yourself but it should be easy to look up with that.  You won't find many options more slim.  If you watch a few laptop or smartphone disassembly videos or rip apart some old hard drive or CD rom drives you should find some in use.

Comment: I have gone through all kinds of FFC. We want type-B type. Nowhere i am getting that cable.

Comment: It's the lowest profile option I'm aware of anyway.  I think with most other options you'll end up losing more boardspace.  I assume you've already looked for female pin connectors that would function when cut down to 1.4mm...  You could just use spring loaded contacts actually right onto pads on the board.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Andyaka is correct.  We can brainstorm potential solutions or sometimes tell you the name of things, but shopping questions are forbidden.

Answer (score 5):

Good ol' [compression connectors](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-spring-loaded/408?k=&pkeyword=&pv28=2250&pv28=2392&pv28=2393&pv28=2350&sf=0&FV=ffe00198&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500) are often used in mobile phones for batteries, [board to board](http://datasheets.avx.com/UltraLowProfileStacker_00-9258.pdf), SIMs, shields and even antennas. You can find them assembled in rectangular housing or get individual contacts for even smaller distances.

[image]

If your boards are mounted permanently another option is to use [elastomeric connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector), but they are prone to aging failures. I sometimes think manufacturers use them to make sure devices will fail just as warranty expires...

Comment: Thank you for suggesting one more way of connecting the boards! I will check for the possibility and will get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, as the comments mention, is to use a low-profile FFC connector. For example, [10062827-0810EDLF](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/18/10062827-1273992.pdf) is less than 1mm thick when closed, and can easily fit between the PCBs.

Using a flex cable has the advantage of not requiring precise PCB positioning, which board-to-board connectors do.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1) We had chosen similar FPC cable and FPC connector. But the problem is of the length of the cable. There is no much spacing around the 2 PCBs to wrap the FPC cable. 2) The minimum length that one can get is around 20 mm. We need still less than that. Please suggest some other means of connecting the boards.